# Writing JS in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

toggler.addEventListener('click', toggleMB);

devtools shows, that AddEventListener in line above is typeerror. It is normal for wordpress, and it couldn't support js, or it is depend from rules of enqueueing scripts?

This if full script file:

```
let toggler = document.querySelector('.menutoggle');
let mbMenu = document.querySelector('.sidemenu');
let mbMenuBack = document.querySelector('.sidelayout');
// let marker = document.querySelector('.ltbottommenu');

  function toggleMB(){
      console.log('hooh')
      mbMenu.classList.toggle('sidemenu__active');
        
        
      if (mbMenu.classList.contains('sidemenu__active')) {
          toggler.childNodes[0].src = "/assets/img/cross.svg"
          toggler.classList.add('menutoggle__active');
          mbMenuBack.classList.add('sidelayout__show');
      }
      else {
          toggler.classList.remove('menutoggle__active');
          mbMenuBack.classList.remove('sidelayout__show');
          toggler.childNodes[0].src = "/assets/img/menu.svg"
      }

  };

  toggler.addEventListener('click', toggleMB);

  mbMenuBack.addEventListener('click', toggleMB);
```

This is script from
function.php file in wordpress:

```
wp_enqueue_script ( 'script-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), '1.0.0', false);
```

Comment: `addEventListener('click', toggleMB());` wrong... You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event hander.

Comment: What is the exact error.message?

Comment: error in chrome:  
VM90 main.js:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at VM90 main.js:28
(anonymous) @ VM90 main.js:28

Comment: So that error clearly states it can not find the element.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `()` from `mbMenuBack.addEventListener('click', toggleMB());` to become: `mbMenuBack.addEventListener('click', toggleMB);` 2nd parameter has to be a function not a result from one.

Better yet implement them as anonymous functions or use a newer technology.

Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_addeventlistener.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
toggler.addEventListener('click', toggleMB());
```

You are calling the function toggleMB here, when adding an event listener. You shouldn't do that. Instead, you should put

```
toggler.addEventListener('click', toggleMB);
```

This way you are binding a function to an event, so the event will call the function when invoked.

Comment: I'm delete call function, but error still appear.